# AJAX Contact Form No-Refresh on submit

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to make my personal portfolio, and I am using this template to do so https://w3layouts.com/one-page-personal-portfolios-flat-bootstrap-responsive-web-template/.
I finished everything except I can not manage to activate contact form.
I tried using ajax script and jquery validator script but with no success.
I wish contact form to be submited without refreshing the page and displaying message if message is sent.
Also I want to use SMTP for that.
Thanks

```
<div class="contact">           <div class="col-md-4 contactgrid">
                <input type="text" class="text" value=" name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = ' name';}">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 contactgrid">
                <input type="text" class="text" value="email" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'email';}">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 contactgrid">
                <input type="text" class="text" value="phone" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'phone';}">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 contactgrid1">
                <textarea onfocus="if(this.value == 'Your Message') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value='Your Message';" >Your Message</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 contactgrid2">
                <input type="button" value="[send message]">
               </div>
               <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Be free to download template, there is only index.html, rename it to index.php and you can try managing this yourself.
Template is free

Comment: Where is your code?!

Comment: Download template, my code is not successful so i deleted it.
IF i knew the code i wouldn't ask

Comment: You say "without success", but what _exactly_ went wrong? e.g. when you load the page or try to submit the form, do you have any errors in the browser console (press F12)? Have you definitely loaded all the required JS libraries etc? Just saying "it didn't work" is not, unfortunately, going to get you much help - there could be 1000 reasons to guess without seeing the details.

Comment: I only need someone to make contact form, using smtp, with ajax, on submit show message succes without refreshing.
THat is all.I will implement it easy if i have working example

Comment: "I need someone to make". SO is not a free coding service. You post the code _you've_ tried, post the error or unexpected behaviour you're getting vs your expected outcome, and then people suggest solutions to your _specific_ problems. No-one will write a whole page or module for you from the start, especially not when there are lots of examples of what you're asking for online already, but you don't seem to want to experiment with them properly.

Comment: No one is asking too, i fixed this long time ago

Answer (score 1):

Chances are the refresh is caused by an input with type='submit'. Change that to a type='button' and it wont submit and cause the refresh. Next you will need to attach an ajax handler to the click event to post the data in the background.

Comment: That is great, but I am new into this. SO i do not really know how.
I posted some code. Perhaps you can post me example using my code on fiddle?